# Is there a way to manage to share revenue with a WordPress online store?

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

Let's say I have a WordPress website that will sell WordPress Templates.

I want to assign roles. For example, Partners that will upload their templates. And I would like to split the revenue: 30% for site owner and 70% for partner.

Is it possible to do this with WordPress? If so, what plugins will allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: The solution heavily relies on your e-commerce system. Do you have one in place, or are you looking to set that up as well?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. I'm not tied to any e-commerce system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [MarketPress](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/e-commerce) has the functionality for that. Says it does on the homepage. Pretty flexible and robust plugin, I recently wrote a mod for it.

Comment: Just wanted to add a quote from the page:
_And, did you know that MarketPress is also 100% WordPress Multisite and BuddyPress compatible - so you can use it to start your own Etsy or Ebay style network of stores... where you take a % on each sale!!!_